# On Lipschitz Quaternions

Tags: number-theory

I have been asked to prove 3 things about the Lipschitz Quaternion $A = \mathbb{Z}\ +\ i\mathbb{Z}\ +\ j\mathbb{Z}\ +\ k\mathbb{Z}$.

$(a)$ I have to prove that for every non-zero left ideal $I \subset A$. $$|A/I| =  \begin{cases}
       n^2 &\text{if and only if $I$ is principal}\\
       2n^2 &\text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}$$

$(b)$ For every prime $p \neq 2$, we have $A/pA \cong \text{Mat}_2(\mathbb{F_p})$

$(c)$ For every prime $p$, there exists an ideal $I \subset A$ with $|A/I|=p^2$. How many such ideals are there?

I believe that $(c)$ will follow from $(a)$ and $(b)$

I know posting multiple questions is frowned upon. But since they arise from a common structure,  I decided to post it.

Looking for any sort of hint to help me solve $(a), (b)\ \& \ (c)$. Very, very stuck.

I'm also aware that $|\text{Cl}(A)|=2$ (the class number). As mentioned here: [Ideal class “group” of Lipschitz (fully-integer) quaternions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964945/ideal-class-group-of-lipschitz-fully-integer-quaternions)

Comment: While flooding the site with questions is frowned upon, especially when are homework questions, asking a couple in the same day is fine. On the other hand, here it isn't clear what *your* question is...

Comment: Fortunately, they're not assignment questions, not exactly. This post-finals let's-solve-questions-that-I-didn't-before phenomenon
Questions are $a,\ b,\ c$

Comment: When you say $I$ is PID in item (a), what do you mean exactly?  That $I$ is a principal ideal?  To say $I$ is PID seems to mean $I$ is a domain, which to me means $1 \in I$; but then $I = A$.

Comment: Yes, I do mean it's Principal Idea. But I don't get your point about PID means that $I$ is a domain, which means $1 \in I$

Comment: @junkquill: that is my point.  If $I$ *were* a domain, $1 \in I$ by definition of a domain as I know it, so then $I = A$.  "PID" is standard terminology for "principle ideal domain", which is a commutative ring with unit, no zero divisors, and every ideal of the form $(a)$.  So I guess you mean $I$ is a principle ideal, but not a PID.

Comment: Oh, crap. You're absolutely right. Grave typographical error on my part